# Why my sound is mute?

Tags: macos, mac, mac-mini

I have problem with my mac mini, sound icon is mute and i am unable to click to unmute it.

Tomorrow night it was working fine, but getting issue now, i inserted headPhone but nothing happen.

[image]

and

[image]

list of Audio devices uder System Report

[image]

Comment: When you click on the Output tab - what is selected? Have you gently inserted a headphone into the speaker port on the back and then removed it? Sometimes the hardware thinks a plug is connected and the software agrees to not play sounds when the hardware thinks external speakers are connected.

Comment: I have the same problem with an old mini: headphones work fine but internal speakers don't appear in the sound preference panel.

Comment: @Rajneesh071 Do you mean "Last night it was working fine...." ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18950/cant-un-mute-sound-when-mini-jack-unplugged and http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/75477/auto-mute-macbook-on-headphone-removal

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis its not solving my problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved automatically when i updated with latest version of OS.

Thanks for your valuable answers and response.
Than

Answer (score 0):

From the screen shots you posted it appears that your Mac doesn't think it has any sound output devices.

This could indicate a hardware fault.  If after rebooting your Mac there are still no output devices listed in `System Preferences > Sound` try running a system report.

You can access this by choosing `About this Mac` from the Apple () Menu and then pressing the `System Report...` button.

On the left of the System Report window there should be a section for `Audio`.  If you select that you will get a list of Audio devices.  If that is empty you most probably have a hardware fault and need to take your Mac to an Apple Store for repair.

Comment: check my answer..screenshot of list of Audio devices uder System Report, there is nothing under device.. :(

Answer (score 0):

You may try resetting your SMC and NVRAM, which controls power for various components as well as retains settings for a few pieces of hardware.

To reset the SMC on your Mac Mini:

1. Shut down your system and unplug all cables (including power cable)
2. Wait 15 seconds at least
3. Plug power and other cables back in
4. Boot machine

To reset the NVRAM:

1. Shut down your Mac.
2. Locate the following keys on the keyboard: Command (⌘), Option, P,
   and R.
3. Turn on your Mac.
4. Press and hold the Command-Option-P-R keys immediately after you
   hear the startup sound.
5. Hold these keys until the computer restarts and you hear the startup
   sound for a second time.
6. Release the keys.

Aside from that, running an Apple Hardware Test by holding D on boot, then running through the prompts to validate if an issue has been found with the actual hardware for the sound.